# How to encrypt string and send it to database

Tags: java, android, json, encryption

i'm new here and couldn't find answer to my question on google.

I have a problem. I need to encrypt some strings in my android application and send it to database encrypted.

My SignUp class: http://wklej.org/id/1237607/

My AESEncrypter class: http://wklej.org/id/1237615/

And here is my question: how can i do it in way which json could undestand it (need to send it parsed)?? Please help. I hope you know what i'm talking about.

Comment: can you please add some comments to your code, and give some examples of usage?

Comment: Do you want to construct json which contains encrypted data?

Comment: @up yes exactly, and send it to db as string

Answer (score 0):

JSON is basically text. You can use base 64 to convert ciphertext to a string, and send that as JSON value. On the server, base64 decode the ciphertext and decrypt it.

Notes on the linked source (AESEncrypter):

- the salt should be random (generated by `new SecureRandom()`) and send with the ciphertext
- the IV may be set to all zero's if a new salt is generated for each plaintext, or should be created using `new SecureRandom()` as well
- AES CBC does not provide integrity protection, nor protection against padding oracle attacks
- Kudos for choosing PBKDF2 and a high iteration count, a secure cipher, and correct (character)encoding/decoding

Comment: Anything missing from my answer? Please either accept or indicate why the answer is not sufficient.